# Why does this for-loop take too much time and space in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner of Python. I am running a for loop to calculate a value out of two lists. Suppose I have two lists like,

```
import random
random.seed(9001)
help=[random.randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
out=[random.randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
```

I want to calculate summation of `[abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out]`

So I used the following code.

```
diff = [abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out]
print sum(diff)
```

When I try to run this code, it takes too much time and hard drive space. Why do I have this problem?

What is a better way to calculate the value I want to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to avoid the allocation of the big list *(see below)*:

```
diff = (abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out)
print sum(diff)
```

### However

You might want to consider if you **really** want `sum([abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out])`

This equation explains the relationship between your `list`s:

```
len(diff)=len(out)*len(help)
```

Which in your case is **10e5*10e5** which is **10e10 = [400-800 GigaByte](https://www.google.de/search?q=10e10%20bytes&oq=10e10%20bytes&aqs=chrome..69i57.2209j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=bytes%20to%20gb)** depending how long your `int`s are.This is not going to fit your disk, and most likely going to take too much time, even with a generator.

---

Most likely you just want to multiply `out[0]` with `help[0]`, `out[1]` with `help[1]` and so on. Then you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or its generator pendant [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to achieve this fast:

```
from itertools import izip

sum(abs(i - 0.77*j) for i,j in izip(help,out))
```

If you do not plan to reuse `help` and `out` you can write the fastest variant:

```
from itertools import izip

sum(abs(i - 0.77*j) for i,j in izip(xrange(100000),xrange(100000))
```

Some measurements:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: random.seed(9001)
In [3]: help=[random.randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
In [4]: out=[random.randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
```

**zip**

```
In [8]: %timeit sum(abs(i - 0.77*j) for i,j in zip(help,out))
10 loops, best of 3: 62.9 ms per loop
```

**izip**

```
In [11]: In [8]: %timeit sum(abs(i - 0.77*j) for i,j in izip(help,out))
10 loops, best of 3: 50.8 ms per loop
```

**xrange**

```
In [17]: help=xrange(10**5)

In [18]: out=xrange(10**5)

In [19]: %timeit sum(abs(i - 0.77*j) for i,j in izip(help,out))         
10 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ms per loop
```

**The original idea**

```
In [21]: help=range(1000)
In [22]: out=range(1000)    
In [24]: %timeit sum([abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out])
1 loops, best of 3: 316 ms per loop
```

`10e4*10e4` is still computing.

**Update**

```
In [25]: help=range(10000)
In [26]: out=range(10000) 
In [27]: %timeit sum([abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out])
1 loops, best of 3: 2min 46s per loop
```

The growth factor going from `10e3**2` to `10e4**2` is **553**, which means `10e5**2` is expected to take 25h30m.

Comment: I don't get the "assuming python2.x"... generator expressions are there in python3 too and *nobody* uses python1.x (or python2.x with x < 4).

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about the lists when I wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

`[abs(i - 0.77*j) for i in help for j in out]` is going to be an array that contains 100000²=10¹⁰ integers. That's 37Gb of data. Are you sure you don't want to compute the following array instead?

```
[abs(i - 0.77*j) for i, j in zip(help, out)]
```

That would be an array of 100000 elements.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is the documentation on `zip`.